# EditText is not taking numeric input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an EditText view in my android application. My EditText is not taking integer values as an input however it is taking all the other ones. the following is my EditText View.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtSearchItems"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible"
android:hint="Search"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</EditText>
```

Comment: It takes integer input. I check ur code.

Comment: It doesn't take integers? Or do you mean it only takes text?  I do not see why it would not allow numeral characters.

Comment: have you tap/click on your [12..] key in keyboard ?

Comment: it is not showing any error in LogCat. I have two devices Motorola and samsung galaxy. On samsung galaxy, EditText View is taking numeric values however in motorola it is not taking the numeric keys.

Comment: another behavior that i am facing is that it is not deleting the characters when i press DEL key on android keyboard. this behavior is present on both devices.

Comment: @AsadIqbal The edittext is not take value from your keyboard's numeric keypad.

Comment: @AsadIqbal testing in emulator or device?

Comment: @RobinHood i am testing it on device , Samsung and Motorola and HTC . On Motorola = Not taking digits input and not deleting text. and on HTC it is taking numeric input but not deleting text from EditText view

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### On the possible issue that i faced once and suspects is: The EditText might be contained in an XML layout file and the layout file will be used for a Dialog instance. The problem occurs when the onKeyListener of the Dialog instance is returning some invalid default value i.e. 'return true' for irrelevant keys. In such case your EditText will be behaving strangely. The sample code for the scenario is

```
Dialog d=new Dialog(context);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    d.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                            KeyEvent event) {
                        Log.i("onkey", keyCode + " == Onkey");
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                                return true;
                        }
                        return true;  // !!! this is wrong it should be return false;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Dialog d=new Dialog(context);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    d.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
          KeyEvent event) {
         Log.i("onkey", keyCode + " == Onkey");
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           return true;
         }
         return true;  // !!! this is wrong it should be return true;
        }
       });
      }

Comment: Nice answer. This is the problem I faced

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

If it works, you can add letters in with the numbers in digits that you want to allow. Here's a [handy list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) of all the inputTypes you could try. They mostly change what appears on the soft keyboard.

Comment: I tried it but not helpful, Cannot understand what is going wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `android:inputType="number"` in your xml just like follows,

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtSearchItems"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible"
android:hint="Search"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:inputType="number">    <------------- this line added
</EditText>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tested this but not get the successful result. it is Same. it is not taking numeric values.

Comment: @AsadIqbal, seriously ?? isn't it showing you numeric keyboard ?

Comment: It is showing numeric keyboard on device, but when i tap on the buttons it is not take the numeric values in it. in my code i am not doing anything with this EditText view.

Comment: can you please upload your Activity Code ?